# Como modelar sistema de usuarios

Tags: c#, java, banco-de-dados, modelagem, uml

Preciso modelar as classes de um sistema onde tera 2 tipos de Usuario, o usuario comum e o administrador, qual a melhor forma de modelar isso?
Bom irei especificar os atributos que cada um precisam na minha aplicação:

UsuarioComum: nome,login,senha,email,idade,endereço etc...

Administrador: nome,login,senha,email...

Qual a forma mais correta de se modelar?
eu pensei no seguinte:

Classe Abstrata Usuario:nome,login,senha,email.

Classe UsuarioComum herda Usuario, e tera suas particularidades.

Classe administrador herda Usuario, e não tem nada a +.

É correto administrador ficar sem nenhuma particularidade? pois se ele herda Usuario, ja esta feito, ou seja a classe administrador vai ficar em branco, isso é correto? se não qual a melhor forma?
obrigado

Comment: Você quer modelar um sistema de usuários independente da tecnologia? Há Frameworks que já fazem este trabalho pra você, mas dependem da tecnologia.

Comment: eu quero um modelo apenas, isso serve pra qualquer tecnologia.

Comment: Ainda me defini quanto a esta pergunta, não sei se não está claro ou é muito ampla. Na minha concepção está difícil respondê-la. A não ser que você queira só saber se sua ideia inicial é boa, se há algum problema no geral. Se for isto, você está no caminho certo, nada errado. Mas sem detalhes fica difícil responder. No fundo se você tiver todos os detalhes você quase terá a resposta por si próprio e aí talvez surjam dúvidas bem específicas que provavelmente se encaixam perfeitamente aqui.

Comment: Não vejo porque a distinção entre usuário comum e administrador, já que o administrador nada mais é um usuário com todos os privilégios do sistema (ou pelo menos os "configuracionais"). Mas a questão é muito baseada em opiniões, complicada de responder...

Comment: Você mal começou a modelagem e já está usando herança? Herança é pra usar quando precisa, não pra usar só porque existe. Sua modelagem está errada; use atributos ou grupos de usuários para distinguir permissões e não herança. Além disso, a pergunta está muito genérica, não oferece detalhes suficientes para uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa bastante utilizada é separar os conceitos de *Usuário* e *Pessoa* em suas próprias classes.

Dessa forma, *usuário* contém os dados relativos ao uso de de sua aplicação, como login, senha, data do último acesso, data de expiração da senha, e as permissões de segurança dadas a este usuário. Um usuário nem precisa ser uma pessoa, pode ser um outro sistema acessando o seu via uma API. No seu caso você pode até mesmo criar um usuário Administrador que não tem as informações pessoais mas tem todas as permissões.

Por outro lado, *pessoa* representa as informações de uma pessoa física, como nome, data de nascimento, dependentes, endereços, telefones, sexo, etc. Uma pessoa também não precisa ser um usuário do sistema (imagine um filho ou esposa de um usuário.)

Tanto *usuário* como *pessoa* podem ter uma referência um ao outro, tipo `pessoa.IDUsuário` ou `usuario.IDPessoa`.

Comment: Precisamente. Se para acessar o sistema um usuário não precisa de informações adicionais, as informações adicionais pertencem a outra entidade +1.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual o nível de complexidade do seu sistema, mas já que todos os atributos são iguais uma ideia era você ter uma única classe usuário e ter um atributo chamado nivel ou nivelDeAcesso para controlar isso, por exemplo Administrador ser 0, e Usuário Comum 1. Em sistemas pequenos já usei isso e resolveu, por isso depende do seu sistema, se for algo mais complexo você pode dar uma pesquisada por algum Framework de segurança, se for no java por exemplo conheço o [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).

Comment: Eu ja tentei essa solução, porem não sao os mesmos atributos,o usuario comum ele tem Idade, endereço, coisa que administrador nao tem, entao se eu criar um campo nivel, no cadastro do administrador, varios campos iriam ficar em branco, o que pra mim não é a melhor forma, minha pergunta é se minha solução esta correta, ou se voces tem outra ideia...

Comment: O que você fez então está correto sim, é correto sim o Administrador ficar sem nenhuma particularidade, no caso ele fica tendo só o que herdou de usuário mesmo.